# Redis cache in .NET 8 is not taking effect?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, redis, .net-8.0

I am playing with .NET 8 new Aspire feature.

I am using Redis cache following this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/caching/stackexchange-redis-output-caching-component?tabs=dotnet-cli#example-usage) from Microsoft on an application with Razor pages. and I use Orchestration to register the cache following this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/caching/stackexchange-redis-output-caching-component?tabs=dotnet-cli#orchestration).

Here is my code `Program.cs` at the AppHost project

```
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var cache = builder.AddRedisContainer("rediscache");
builder.AddProject<Projects.WeatherApp_Web>("frontend")
    .WithReference(cache)
```

In her is service registration in `Program.cs` of frontend project:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.AddServiceDefaults();
builder.AddRedisOutputCache("rediscache");
etc...
```

And app usage:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseOutputCache();
etc...
```

And of course, in my Razor page class, the duration is set to 5 seconds, only for testing.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 5)]
```

The issue is that the content of the page is updating always and not showing the caching results. There is no error. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently working on something similar and faced the same issue.

To get the cache working, you need to call `app.UseOutputCache();` after routing `app.UseRouting();` which is somewhere in your `Programs.cs` in your frontend project.

So your code should be something like

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

etc...

app.UseRouting();
app.UseOutputCache();

etc...
```

And it will work.

I was able to find this information in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-8.0#add-the-middleware-to-the-app).

> In Razor Pages apps and apps with controllers, UseOutputCache must be
> called after UseRouting.